# 3D matrix summation?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, sum

Is there any way to sum 3 dimensional matrix?

For example if you have data

```
m<-array(c(1:9,18:26,30:38),dim=c(3,3,3))

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   18   21   24
[2,]   19   22   25
[3,]   20   23   26

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   30   33   36
[2,]   31   34   37
[3,]   32   35   38
```

And your answer will be: 549.

Also, if there six 3by3 matrices, how can be every two matrices summed and printed? With for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `sum()` for each of your dimensions, here three:

```
R> m<-array(c(1:9,18:26,30:38),dim=c(3,3,3))
R> sum(sum(sum(m)))
[1] 549
R>
```

Or drop dimensions and call `sum()` on what is now a single vector:

```
R> sum(c(m))
[1] 549
R>
```

*Edit* I overcomplicated things. A 3-array is still just a vector, so all it takes is

```
R> sum(m)
[1] 549
R>
```

Thanks to @thelatemail for the cluebat.

Comment: Won't `sum(m)` just do it?

Comment: Oops. You're correct. But wasn't there a case where it returned rows or cols?  <scratches head...>

Comment: I'm not sure, I've always just assumed an array is a vector with dimensions, hence `sum` etc will work as normal.

Comment: Somewhat sum did not work, and my matrix treat elements as characters. Is there anyway to fix character matrix into numeric? All data I have is numbers.

Comment: Also, if there are 24 matrices, and how to sum every 2 and print them out?

Comment: @Uka - try `m <- apply(m,c(1,2),as.numeric)` to convert your array to numeric without losing your dimensions.